# Gravity amplifier

Tags: gravity, mass, gravitational-waves, modified-gravity

Just a hypothetical question. Is it possible to increase or amplify gravitational interactions between two or more bodies  ( without  changing the mass)?
Will changing the graviton count(theoretically, of course) have an effect?

Comment: shorten the average square distances :)

Comment: I was sort of looking for a hypothesis which couples gravitational field lines thereby increasing their strength

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer:

In Newtonian gravity: definitely no. The gravitational attraction between two bodies depends only on their masses and separation. There is nothing else for the "amplifier" to couple to.

In general relativity: practically speaking, no. For one thing in all "mundane" situations the predictions will be identical to those of Newton.

But just for fun assume one has infinite technology. Then I think the answer in GR is yes. In two ways:

1. Relativistic gravity couples not only to the masses of the objects, but also to their pressures. So, you could amplify the gravity by increasing the pressure density, and this could in principle be done without changing the masses (i.e. the energy densities). I think this isn't really what you have in mind though.
2. One could, I suppose, place a very strong gravitational lens between the two bodies, in just such a way as to focus gravitational radiation (etc) upon them. This could in principle be calibrated in such a way as to increase the attractive force between the bodies.

   While I'm reasonably certain (I'm not 100% sure though) this is *technically* possible, it is likely a very delicate set-up, requiring absurdly difficult engineering (I am basically suggesting one somehow hold two black holes in place at precisely chosen locations), resulting in a very small increase in force. It's hard to imagine a civilization capable of doing this would not be able to simply pull the objects together directly.

In modified-gravity theories one typically does not have an equivalence principle: therefore gravity can couple to things besides the energy/pressure directly (i.e. there are 'extra charges' that the gravity cares about). By manipulating the distribution of the extra charge between the masses one could presumably create an amplifying effect. I'm thinking of something like the 'spontaneous scalarization' of binary neutrons stars in scalar-tensor gravity people have been looking into lately.

Comment: As I added in my question, will changing the graviton count change anything?

Comment: @user2511145 It would depend on the theory in question. One can make just about anything do virtually anything simply by using math. The question is if the theory can explain reality that defines if the theory is realistically good like general relativity and quantum field theory, or not even wrong (impossible to prove or disprove) like string theory, or maybe even impossible like the theory of the aether.

Comment: @user251145 There is no notion of 'graviton count' in GR (or in any well-developed theory of gravity) so this question is hard to answer. However, the classical analog of 'graviton count' would basically be some measure of the gravitational field strength. So changing the 'graviton count' is equivalent to amplifying gravity.